# Vagrant up выдает ошибку Invalid argument

Tags: vagrant

При попытке сделать vagrant up, выходит вот такое сообщение:

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:47:in `[]=': Invalid argument - ruby_setenv(VAGRANT_NO_PLUGINS) (E
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:47:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:36:in `each_index'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:36:in `<main>'
```

Windows 7 x64, Vagrant 2.1.2, virtual box 5.2.16

Как вылечить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ругается, что не хватает нужных плагинов. Открой Vagrantfile и найди строку:
required_plugins = (plagin-name_1, plagin-name_2)
В скобках будет список плагинов, которые нужно установить. Делается простой командой:

```
vagrant plugin install plagin-name
```

Только запускай не в этой директории, выйди на уровень выше